# Scaling Circles

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I have this simple bit of code that draws uses two for loops, one nested inside the other in order to draw a grid of 6x7 circles.

The issue I'm having is currently due to the way I have coded the circleRadius or so I have led myself to believe. What I need is for the scale of these circles look the same across different devices and there screen sizes.

So here is the code  for setting the circleRadius and the loops:

```
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), blue);
    int columnWidth = canvas.getWidth() / Columns;
    int rowHeight = (canvas.getHeight() / Rows);
    int circleRadius = ((canvas.getHeight() / Rows) -160);

    for(int column = 0; column < Columns; column++)
    {
        for(int row = 0; row <Rows; row++){

            if(pos_id == 1){
                canvas.drawCircle((columnWidth*column)+55, (rowHeight*row)+100, circleRadius, red);
            }
            else if(pos_id == 2){
                canvas.drawCircle((columnWidth*column)+55, (rowHeight*row)+100, circleRadius, yellow);
            }
            else if(pos_id == 0){
                canvas.drawCircle((columnWidth*column)+55, (rowHeight*row)+100, circleRadius, white);
            }
        }
    }
```

All help is much appreciated and many thanks in advance

Comment: What is the reason for the `-160` constant?

Comment: Well, you have to scale: radius and x/y distance. The scale factor is given by: **final float scale = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density;**

Comment: Okay so once I've created the scale how am I supposed to use it in order to scale the radius of the circles being drawn?

Comment: perhaps it would be better to base it all on the actual size of the screen for example size the grid based on the screen size and split it into equal sections (divide by number of columns and rows) and set the circles radius relatively